# Why is this small <p> bugging my code while coding a MODAL in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

This file is stored in my index.html.erb file. The Modal works fine until I uncomment this paragraph below. (it's just sample text). Once uncommented, I can no longer navigate to other views in the same controller. Also, the same happens if I uncomment either the popover code or the tooltip code. I have to comment one or the same error happens. Any advice? This is odd.

```
            <div class="span3">
            <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"><span     class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span>Keep Me Posted</a>        

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Keep Me Posted</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>text in body</h4> 
                <!--    <p> n joining us, you can use their web based  application or download their mobile app . Also, we'll soon blast out 
                         a bit more of information about what to expect, what products wil be reviewed, hours of operation, exp </p> --> 
                  <!--      <h4>Popovers in a modal</h4> 
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger pop">Dont click this button</a> -->

                        <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4> 
                   <!--  <a href="">This link</a> should have a tooltip and so should <a href="">this one</a> -->
                    </div> 

                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't navigate to other views? Do the links to other pages stop working? If so, maybe your modal isn't closing and the `<p>` tag is being displayed as a block and is on top of everything else, essentially preventing you fron clicking anything.

Comment: it is closed. it is the commented out <p> tag in the code above. Do you know if empty hrefs ( href="") also give modals issues ?

Comment: Empty hrefs shouldn't affect modals, but they also won't do anything. If you want a clickable link but don't want it to redirect anywhere, it's best to use `href="#"`.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you try to click a link to another view on this page after closing the modal?

Comment: The modal is coded in the index.html.erb then when im on the index page and try to navigate to Othe links like Contact us, Traderoom or bios, then their links dont function. But if you try to come to INDEX link from one of the others, it works fine. here is the link to the app tradertwitch.com

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? `span3` is from Bootstrap v2, but `modal-dialog` and `modal-content` are from Bootstrap v3. And v3 isn't backward-compatible with v2.

Comment: ahh ok, that may be it then, huh ? let me give that a shot. Im just learning bootstrap and getting my ideas from a couple different resources. coud that be throwing a bunch of buginess ?

Comment: how can i check what version I have ? im using Windows, btw. i read that the V would be in the bootstrap.css file, but that was not the case

Comment: If you downloaded the source files for Bootstrap, you should be able to open the .js or .css file and check the version number in the comments that are in the top of the file. If the file ends with .min.js or .min.css and/or is just a big block of "random" text, it's the minimized version of the file, which you can't easily check.

Comment: If you can find the version that you're using, stick to it and try to only look up things related to that version, or else just download one of them again and see which works best for what you currently have, then fix what's different and move on

Comment: Im pretty sure I have Bootstrap2.3. I have deleted code, like the ones you mentioned above, to reflect that. I am still having linking issues ONLY from the index page.+

Comment: Im pretty sure I have Bootstrap2.3. I have deleted code, like the ones you mentioned above, to reflect that. I am still having linking issues ONLY from the index page. I have 5 views (HOME, About Traderoom,BIOS, and Contact) If I am on the ABOUT page, ALL links work fine. If I am on the Home(Index.html.erb) page, then I cannot click on TradeRoom, Bios, or Contact. I can only click on About Us